# given random variable $X$ and function $g(x)$ , can I calculate $E(g(X))$ in a simple way?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

given some random variable $X$, and function $g(x)$.
Exists some formula so that I will can calculate $E(g(X))$ quickly and easily?

---

I ask about some random variable $X$ (without any limitation).

I will be happy to learn new things :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Comment: Look up: law of unconscious statistician.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a random variable with value in $S$, and $g:S\to \mathbb{R}$ a real function, then you can use the formula 
$$
E[g(X)]=\sum_{x\in S}g(x)p_X(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{for $X$ discrete random variable}
$$
and
$$
E[g(x)]= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)f_X(x)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{for $X$ continuous random variable}
$$

Comment: You should probably add that $S$ is at most countable.

Comment: @ MayoDancer Not all continuous random variables have a density.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: No, by definition a random variable $X$ is continuous if it has a density (and integrable ) function $f_X(x)$

Comment: @MayoDancer some people define continuous random variables by requiring that the c.d.f be continuous, in which case a density may be not exist.

Comment: @MayoDancer Have you heard of continuous singular distributions? Your definition of continuous distributions is probably used in pre-measure theoretic probability books.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: no i've never heard of it, can you link me a book, paper or something? tnks

Comment: @MayoDancer Any book on measure theoretic probability, like Billingsley, Chung, Breiman,...

Answer (score 0):

You should state the measure relative to your expectation.

If $X$ follows the Dirac measure at $0$, then yes, $\, E\left(g\left(X\right)\right) = g\left(0\right) \,$.

If $X$ follows a law based on the classic Lebesgue measure $dx$ then no, there is no general way to compute an integral ; in fact we are not able to give an exact value for most functions. As an example, there is no exact value of the integral $\, \int_0^1 e^{-x^2} dx$, which can be interpreted as either the expectation of $\, g\left(X\right) \,$ when $X$ follows the uniform law over $[0;1]$ and $\, g\!\left(x\right) = e^{-x^2} \,$, or the expectation of $\, g\left(X\right) \,$ when $X$ follows the normal law (ie Gaussian of mean $0$ and variance $1$) and $\, g(x) = \sqrt{\pi} 1_{x\in[0;\sqrt{2}]} \,$.

So, in general, if you want a precise value of an integral you often have to rely on a computer (and an algorithm) to get a more or less good approximation value of the integral. 
There are countless methods to try and find the exact value of an integral though ; some of the first ideas you will come upon is integration by parts, change of coordinates, then, later, the residue theorem and the Lebesgue theorem. They will enlarge the set of functions you will be able to integrate exactly, but, as I said, most integrals will not have an exact value. 
If you want to know more, or have an idea of the span and complexity of the subject, look for "Integration theory" or "Measure theory". 
I hope I did understand your question, and, in any case, I wish you well.